# Проблема с запуском редактора atom

Tags: atom

Начал изучать javascript - записался на курс для новичков, es6 на udemy. Там есть видео где описывается процесс подготовки среды для начала программирования https://www.udemy.com/essentials-in-javascript-es6/learn/v4/t/lecture/6423216?start=0.

Я повторяю все, как в этом видео, но когда я ввожу команду atom в командной строке - мне пишет `"atom" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом`.

Помогите мне разобраться, что я делаю не так.

Операционная система у меня Windows10.

Comment: Могу предположить не смотря видео что причина в том что в уроке не используется Windows, вам достаточно просто найти его в пуске или по ярлыку запустить (если вы его установили), это просто команда для запуска редактора.

Comment: Спасибо! Как-то сам об этом не подумал.Все сработало.